# Xamarin Form - TaskCanceledException thrown on await client.PostAsync()

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Very strange problem (all code is in PCL).

When I call `await client.PostAsync()` against a webservice (API's), I get the `TaskCanceledException`.

Few things to note:

This is running fine on Android devices. It only happens when I run the app on iOS, but...

... to make it even stranger, I **can** make it run on iOS if I use different (physical) server that hosts the API's that I query with `await client.PostAsync()`.

So,

- https://somedomainname.com - works fine
- https://someotherserver.com - does not work

To make it even more strange, both servers **run exactly the same webservice**, there is 0 difference, the only difference is the servers are on different sites with different client. So the fault is not with the queried webservice throwing timing out or cancelling the request.

Both servers have valid (trusted) SSL certificate so it's not an SSL related issue.

I am stuck. I have already tried `ModernHttpClient` and increaing the `client.TimeSpan`.

I also checked the `ex.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`, which is false, so it's pretty safe to assume it was some time of "timeout". However, when I run the Post request from PostMan manually against that API, it's clear the webservice works fine (there is no timeout).

```
public class TokenService
{
    private HttpClient client;
    private App app;

    public TokenService()
    {
        //client = new HttpClient();

        client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        app = (App)Application.Current;
    }

    public class TokenResponse
    {
        public String access_token;
        public Int32 expires_in;
    }

    public async Task<String> GetNewToken()
    {
        // check if valid token already stored and within expiry DateTime

        if(Token.BearerToken != null)
        {
            if (Token.expiry > DateTime.Now)
                return Token.BearerToken;
        }

        var tokenUlr = app.WebServicesHostName + "/token";

        var tokenResponse = new TokenResponse();

        try
        {
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                // this needs to be stored somewhere safe:
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "validusernamehere"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "validpasshere")
            });

            var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenUlr, content); // <<***EXCEPTION HERE

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(token);

                Token.BearerToken = tokenResponse.access_token;
                Token.expiry = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.expires_in - 30);

                return tokenResponse.access_token;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;

            }
        }
        catch(TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            String message = ex.Message;
            String source = ex.Source;
            CancellationToken token = ex.CancellationToken;



            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            String test = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Exception details:

> {System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002d] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:179
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+c__async0.MoveNext ()
>   [0x004c1] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:391
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00027] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:176
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+c__async0.MoveNext ()
>   [0x000a9] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00027] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:176
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.4.0.128/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357
>   at XamarinMO.Services.TokenService+d__4.MoveNext ()
>   [0x000e3] in C:\Users\johns\OneDrive\Sources\WinMan API and Xamain
>   App\XamarinMO\XamarinMO\XamarinMO\Services\TokenService.cs:67 }

Comment: Could you post a sample of code ?

Comment: @OrcusZ sure, I amended the post.

Comment: it's very strange. because yoru code seems to be correct. Can you add a `finaly` in your`try catch` and dispose `HttpClient`. Futhermore, do you run this code into a thread or not ?

Comment: Are you able to recreate the problem in a minimal example: New Project, add just the call to your service and see if it works?

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check that the query is returning successfully on iOS.

Comment: @OrcusZ yes, I already tried disposing with finally/using. It's not run in a thread.

Comment: @Kai Brummund This is not the issue - this very same project with its associated API's runs OK with another client on iOS/Android. The only difference is that there is a switch in the project that changes the API's url for the second client because they host the Api's on a different server with different domain name. It runs on Android/iOS for domain1, but only Android for domain2. Crucially, the API is exactly the same on both servers, so it's not an issue with the queried webservice. This was confirmed with Postman and SSL trust validity checks for both API URL's.

Comment: @David Oliver. The query runs successfully on iOS and Android for client #1, but only on Android for client #2. Both clients run this very app and use identical API's - their APIs are host on premises in the client's factories/server room.

Comment: What is the response in Fiddler for iOS + client #2, then? Does it give any clues?

Comment: @David Oliver I haven't run Fiddler on iOS. I am not too proficient in Fiddler anyway so doubtful I could use it meaningfully (plus I run the iOS in emulator on a Mac rented in the cloud via an RDP).

Answer (score 2):

After many MANY hours, I found the solution:

It can be fixed by changing the TLS setting under project properties to Mono instead of Apple. This is due to a bug in the new Apple TLS default setting for SSL/TLS on iOS.

Comment: Where is this option in Mac visual studio 2019